# How To Animate Sheathed Weapon. Sheathe, Player And Weapon Are All Seperate Objects

Tags: bones

I have a character that i can animate properly. I'm still new to blender but know basic animations, basic modeling, texturing and weight painting.

I tried making a seperate bone for the weapon and add both the weapon's bone and character's bones in the action editor with I but then the character moved to the weapon. I used LocRotScale.

I want to later on use the model and animations in Unity. I've done my other characters without weapons fine with action editor with multiple animations.

Comment: A little more info could help, I don't quite get what you are asking . . .

Comment: I'm trying to make the character grab the sheathed sword from their back and then i would move both the hand and sword where i want them and would try to make a swing animation. I thought adding a bone to the sword would make the bones work better together but instead they seemed to merge. I'd simply like to move the sword seperately from the character but put the frames from both objects into the same animation, so i could easily import it to blender. I don't know how to do this at all. I'm not sure what other information you need but you can always ask in depth too.